# QGIS macOS Installer Version 3.2 and Python 3.6, Mac OS Mojave

Tags: qgis, python

I downloaded QGIS version 3.2 and (I think) followed the install directions correctly: first I installed Python 3.6 from the Python website, then I installed GDAL, but when I install QGIS I get the errors mentioned elsewhere in the forum, "QGIS requires Python 3.6".  From reading other posts, it seems like installing Python directly from the Python website was the solution to others with the same error - this may have corrected incorrect paths.

Any thoughts on what else I can try?

[image]

[image]

Comment: `/usr/bin/python` or `pythonw` is the Python version 2.7.x  pre-installed by Apple. `/usr/local/bin/python3` is the Python 3.6.x version

Comment: Thanks for your response Gene.  In the Python Preferences I changed the path to "/usr/local/bin/python3" in Script, GUI Script and Bytecode Document, then I reinstalled GDAL (not sure if this was necessary) and then tried to install QGIS, but I still get the same error.  Any other ideas of what I'm missing?  Thank you!

Comment: Oops. From reading another post, I now realize that I accidentally installed Python 3.7 instead of 3.6.  With Python 3.6 now installed, I successfully installed QGIS 3.2.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem: On Mojave the default python version seems 3.7 and As downgrading to python3.6 with `brew switch python 3.6.x`, didn't make the installer error go away I installed qgis over brew:

```
brew install gdal
brew cask install xquartz
pip3 install matplotlib
pip3 install psycopg2
brew tap osgeo/osgeo4mac
brew install qgis3
```

The version I ended up with is `3.4.1-Madeira`